# Oracle nested query

Tags: sql, oracle

Essentially I'm attempting to select the top read (based on `read_date`), and check if it has a `type in ( 'R','S','C','B','Q','F','I','A')`

```
select *
from (
        select *
        from (
           select *
           FROM table
           WHERE  id = 369514
           order by read_date desc
            )
         where rownum = 1
         )
 where type IN ( 'R','S','C','B','Q','F','I','A')
```

I only need to return a row if the top row has a type in the set, if not return nothing.

The only way I seem to be able to is using all these nasty sub-queries.

Comment: is this Query slow? is it inefficient?

Comment: not slow, just looked like it could probably be improved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking at the Query and you should be able to get rid of the outside Select.

```
select *
from (
      select *
      FROM table
      WHERE  id = 369514
      order by read_date desc
      )
where rownum = 1 AND type IN ( 'R','S','C','B','Q','F','I','A')
```

I don't have anything to Test against, but it looks like this would work.

Comment: I've actually realised this myself and removed it.  I've upvoted :-)